# Uses of Python's "from" keyword?

Tags: python, import, python-3.x, keyword, python-2.x

Are there any other uses for Python's "from" keyword aside from `import` statements?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No and yes.

According to the [official Python 2.7.2 grammar](http://docs.python.org/reference/grammar.html), the only occurrence of the word `from` is in the clause `import_from`, so no.

In the [Python 3.1.3 grammar](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/reference/grammar.html) a new clause

```
raise_stmt: 'raise' [test ['from' test]]
```

appears, so yes.

Answer (score 19):

There is a new [syntax for delegating to a subgenerator](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) in Python 3.3 which uses the `from` keyword.

Comment: So in conclusion, from Python 3.3+ `from` can be used with raise and yield in addition to imports?

Answer (score 17):

In Python 2.x,  the only use of `from` is for the `from x import y` statement. However, for Python 3.x, it can be used in conjunction with the `raise` statement, e.g.:

```
try:
    raise Exception("test")
except Exception as e:
    raise Exception("another exception") from e
```

Comment: What does this do, exactly? Is the original exception implicitly chained somehow? That seems un-Pythonic to me; better to explicitly take it as a constructor parameter... so surely it does something else?

Comment: Personally I've never used it -- I just know it exists, and it's intended to be for raising an exception that was directly caused by another.

Answer (score 3):

Since there are a lot of updates to python from the time of posting the question, here is a new use case of **from** keyword in python3
will show you the use with an example

```
def flatten(l):
    for element in l:
        if type(element) == type(list()):
            yield from flatten(element)
        else:
            yield element

def flatten2(l):
    for element in l:
        if type(element) == type(list()):
            yield flatten2(element)
        else:
            yield element


unflatted_list = [1,2,3,4,[5,6,[7,8],9],10]
flatted_list = list(flatten(unflatted_list))
flatted_list2 = list(flatten2(unflatted_list))
print(flatted_list) # [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print(flatted_list2) # [1, 2, 3, 4, <generator object flatten2 at 0x000001F1B4F9B468>, 10]
```

Comment: the `type(...) == list` comparison here is redundant since `yield from <expr>` only works when `<expr>` is an Iterable.

Answer (score 2):

The following use

```
from __future__ import some_feature
```

is syntactically identical to an import statement but instead of importing a module, it changes the behavior of the interpreter in some fashion, depending on the value of `some_feature`.

For example, `from __future__ import with_statement` allows you to use Python's `with` statement in Python 2.5, even though the `with` statement wasn't added to the language until Python 2.6.  Because it changes the parsing of source files, any `__future__` imports must appear at the beginning of a source file.

See the [`__future__` statement documentation](httP://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#future-statements) for more information.

See the [`__future__` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/__future__.html) for a list of possible `__future__` imports and the Python versions they are available in.

Comment: Did you mean to post this as an answer for another question? It seems only tangentially related to this one...

Comment: Actually, it does import from the `__future__` module, too.

Comment: @Karl: No, I did not.  Yes, `__future__` is a module, and importing from `__future__` is an import statement.  But my point is that while importing from future is syntactically the same as any other import, the *semantics* are different from a vanilla import.  It's not just importing other symbol names, it's also changing the behavior of the interpreter in an important way.

Comment: @Karl @Benj - The Python docs specifically call this a `__future__ statement` -- it looks like an `import statement` but it's not. If you actually want to import the `__future__` module, you have to do `import __future__`.

Answer (score 2):

With the finalization of [PEP 3134](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/), the `from` keyword can be used when an exception is generated (`raise`) as a consequence of catching an exception in a `try-except` block.

```
try:
    <some code>
except <exception type> as e:
    raise <exception> from e
```

The keyword `from` allows to keep track of the caught exception `e` in the new excaption raised. The exception `e` will be stored in the attribute `__cause__` of the new exception.