# Using "from" as an argument name

Tags: python, function

Given the function header:

```
myfunction(from):
  #some code
```

I get a syntax error. Is this because "from" is a keyword in Python? If so are all keywords barred from being used as variable names?

Comment: Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219082/uses-of-pythons-from-keyword) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595922/list-of-python-keywords). Try to make a greater effort at research before posting questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a keyword so you can't use it as a name, try:

```
def my_function(from_):
   # some code
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Is this a common convention in Python to use "keyword_" if you desire to use a keyword as a variable?

Comment: Since `_from` _convention_ is used for private names, I use `from_`, or e.g. `from_email` to avoid the keyword conflict

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095188/is-there-a-python-naming-convention-for-avoiding-conflicts-with-standard-module) for info about a trailing underscore.