# Cython - use of "from" keyword in for loop

Tags: python, cython

I was recently reading some source code from sklearn's [BallTree](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/neighbors/ball_tree.pyx) class, which is written in Cython, and I came across some [bizarre syntax](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/neighbors/ball_tree.pyx#L71) in a for loop:

```
for j from 0 <= j < n_features:
    centroid[j] += this_pt[j]
```

After some looking around, I'm unable to find any documentation for the use of the `from` keyword in a `for` loop. In fact, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219082/uses-of-pythons-from-keyword) explicitly states that the only use of `from` in Python is in the `import_from` clause.

Though it reads strangely, my interpretation of the line is essentially:

```
for j in range(n_features):
    ...
```

...which adheres to the condition that `j` start with `0` and remain less than `n_features`.  What exactly is the advantage of the strange syntax, and is it doing something differently than I expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an [oldie that was retained for compatibility](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/language_basics.html#integer-for-loops) with [pyrex](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Pyrex) (a cython predecessor).

```
for i from 0 <= i < n:
```

is equivalent to

```
for i in range(n):
```

You should note that it is deprecated.

Comment: Ok, so it is essentially just `for i in range(n)` but in legacy form?

Comment: Yes. You should avoid using it now.

Answer (score 3):

It is a legacy form.

*For backwards compatibility to Pyrex, Cython also supports a more verbose form of for-loop which you might find in legacy code:*

```
for i from 0 <= i < n:
```

Taken from [Cython docs](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/language_basics.html#integer-for-loops)